# plotting stem with a continuous line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a stem plot of my signal using python and matplotlib.

I saw the example and the code but the line connecting the black big dot and the x-axis is not a continous line. Do you know whether is possible and how to get a straight line instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0.1, 2*pi, 10)
markerline, stemlines, baseline = stem(x, cos(x), '-.')
setp(markerline, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')
setp(baseline, 'color','r', 'linewidth', 2)

show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `'-.'` to `'-'`:

```
markerline, stemlines, baseline = stem(x, cos(x), '-')
```

The final argument indicates the [line style](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).